# 2 accordions side by side

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I want to create 2 different accordions as 2 buttons side by side of each other. How do I add 2 accordions to work as separate accordions? Here is my jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({
  heightStyle: "content" 
});
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible : true, active : 'none'
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Those jquery queries both target all elements with the accordian class. You probably want to use either ID selection or give the two different elements different classes.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use unique selectors. Give them an ID an initialize them separately.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( "#accordion1" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content" 
  });
  $( "#accordion2" ).accordion({
    collapsible : true, active : 'none'
  });
  return false;
});
```